# All but first deployment of Orchard CMS to Azure Web Apps Fails

Tags: azure, orchardcms, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy, azure-devops

In Visual Studio Online I have a scripted build that builds Orchard 1.9.1 from source then, using the *Azure Web App Deployment* task, deploys the compiled Web Deploy Package to Azure.

The first deployment to a fresh Web App instance works great and the system functions as expected. However, any subsequent deployment to the same Web App fails with:

> Unable to perform the operation ("Delete File") for the specified
>   directory ("HtmlAgilityPack.dll"). This can occur if the server
>   administrator has not authorized this operation for the user
>   credentials you are using. Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_SITE_FOLDER.

The file specified in the error can be different, but the deployment fails consistently. The link in the error isn't of much help as the implementation details covered (IIS, root folder etc) are abstracted away in an Azure Web App.

Where should I look to fix this permissioning issue?

I went with the default build template for *Azure Website* when creating the build, details of which are below for info:

**Build Step:**
[image]

MSBuild Arguments:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true 
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.stagingDirectory)"
```

---

**Azure Web App Deployment step:**
[image]

---

**Pertinent information for the build log:**

```
2015-09-28T05:36:22.7928424Z Package= C:\a\d8c9303e\staging\Orchard.Web.zip     
2015-09-28T05:36:22.7938416Z Slot=      
2015-09-28T05:36:22.7938416Z AdditionalArguments=      
2015-09-28T05:36:22.8028415Z packageFile= Find-Files -SearchPattern C:\a\d8c9303e\staging\Orchard.Web.zip     
2015-09-28T05:36:22.8198428Z packageFile= C:\a\d8c9303e\staging\Orchard.Web.zip     
2015-09-28T05:36:22.8258420Z Get-AzureWebSite -Name **** -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue     
2015-09-28T05:36:28.4361621Z Publish-AzureWebsiteProject -Name "****" -Package "C:\a\d8c9303e\staging\Orchard.Web.zip"     
2015-09-28T05:36:33.8798112Z ##[error]Unable to perform the operation ("Delete File")  for the specified directory ("HtmlAgilityPack.dll"). This can occur if the server administrator has not authorized this operation for the user credentials you are using.     
2015-09-28T05:36:33.8818107Z ##[error]  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_SITE_FOLDER.
```

Comment: Can you use the specific `Orchard.proj` msbuild script and specify the `Precompiled` target instead?

Comment: Thanks @SébastienRos-MSFT, looking into that now. Could you elaborate on what that should change in terms of the deployment step?

Comment: Maybe it won't try to update this dll as it should only be in App_data/dependencies and Precompiled would never create this file, it's copied at runtime.

Comment: Great, that seems to have worked. Thank- you! If you want to post the answer I can accept it. One thing is I'd like to retain `app_data`, as now the deployment has worked I'm back at the initial set up screen. What would be the best way of doing this with a Azure Web App deployment?

Comment: I don't know how to make the deployment not delete a specific folder but just update the existing ones. I know that Kudu supports this in a very clever way. Have you tried using it? It would connect to your git repos, update it, build and deploy all from Azure directly.

Comment: Shouldn't the solution be `$/Src/Orchard.Azure/Orchard.Azure.sln` ?

Comment: @pero what did you do exactly to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use the provided `Orchard.proj` msbuild script using the `Precompiled` target.

Comment: Could you elaborate the answer? I have the same issue but can not figure out how to achieve this - Use the provided Orchard.proj msbuild script using the Precompiled target.